# LiveAgent with Pre-Chat Visualforce page always appears Offline

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I am following the steps in http://peterknolle.com/live-agent-pre-chat-api/ to setup a pre-chat form that will allow the system to capture information about the person, the agent is going to chat with.

- I have got the Live Agent Deployment with the option to access pre-chat api checked and enter the permitted domains.
- I have the button configured to use a pre-chat page
- I have created http://jsfiddle.net/deepuchacko/nJShf/3/ that hosts the deployment and button code.
- I am part of the Skills

Even though I have logged into the org as Agent and made myself Online on Live Agent, the jsfiddle keeps showing Offline. I know this is not right because I have another button configuration that does not have a pre-chat form and the http://jsfiddle.net/deepuchacko/nJShf/1/ for it shows as Online. Any thoughts on why the system might think the agents are offline?

Comment: Have you tried this from a local file or a visualforce page?

Comment: @PepeFloyd I have tried this from a local file and still the page shows that am offline (same behavior as described above). With all the googling, I noticed that you and PeterKnolle are two people who have been successful in getting LiveAgent to work with pre-chat forms. Unfortunately following the dev guide and peter's article has not been fruitful.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons the button could be offline. Have you tried enabling debug logs on your deployment page? Adding `liveagent.enableLogging();` before the init call, and before calling any other Live Agent APIs, often results in useful information being output to the JS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a few domains set in the Permitted Domains field of Deployment (Setup -> Customize -> Live Agent -> Deployments). Once I removed the domains, my status as well as the pre-chat form popped up.